# EF Code First MVC Setting Default Value on a Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Just looking for some general guidance here.  Essentially I am building a project with EF Code First MVC Model and I have a class with a number of methods and I want to set the value of one method based on values in two other methods using If Statements.

I have searched every where, been reading books, doing tutorials etc but no one seems to be covering what I am trying to do.  I suspect I am missing something obvious or it is not possible for me to achieve what I am doing.

An excerpt from my code below - I am trying to set the value of the Rating Field based on the Values in the Probability and Severity Field.  I have tried modifying the get and set statements, setting in constructors etc.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PSA.Models
{
    public class Issue
    {
        public virtual int IssueID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is Required.")]
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual string Type { get; set; }
        public virtual string Classification { get; set; }
        public virtual bool Internal { get; set; }
        public virtual int ProbableStatusId { get; set; }
        public virtual ProbableStatus ProbableStatus{ get; set; }
        public virtual int SeverityStatusId { get; set; }
        public virtual SeverityStatus SeverityStatus { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Due Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public virtual DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Assigned To")]
        public int StakeholderID { get; set; }
        public virtual Stakeholder Stakeholder { get; set; }
        [Display(Name= "Customer")]
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }

        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public virtual DateTime DateSubmitted { get; set; }
        public virtual string Rating { get; set; }


        // Constructor used to initialise any new instance of Date Submitted with System Date and Time
        public Issue()
        {
            this.DateSubmitted = DateTime.Now;
        }

   }

}
```

Comment: Give us more info on what you tried and what you need

Comment: What do you mean by setting the value of a method?

Comment: If you are talking about the value of a property, then you can implement get for that property and return the value based on other two properties.

Comment: Thank you everyone - the answer was to set the conditions and return in the get statement.  Simple really I just didn't understand exactly what the get statement was doing for me

Answer (score 1):

You can create a calculated property:

```
[NotMapped]
public virtual SeverityStatus SeverityStatus
{
    get
    {
        // Implement your calculation logic here
        if (ProbableStatusId == 1 && SeverityStatusId == 1)
            return new SeverityStatus();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note:
You cannot do this in your constructor because the two related properties are null. Another solution would be the creation of a method

Comment: Thank you - Essentially you are right the answer was in putting all the logic in the get statement.  I solved it a slightly different way but your answer was very helpful.

Comment: Please add your code to help others and mark your question as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone - the answer was to set the conditions and return in the get statement. Simple really I just didn't understand exactly what the get statement was doing for me.

Code is shown below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PSA.Models
{
    public class Issue
    {
        public virtual int IssueID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is Required.")]
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual string Type { get; set; }
        public virtual string Classification { get; set; }
        public virtual bool Internal { get; set; }
        public virtual int ProbableClassificationId { get; set; }
        public virtual ProbableClassification ProbableClassification { get; set; }
        public virtual int SeverityClassificationId { get; set; }
        public virtual SeverityClassification SeverityClassification { get; set; }
        string ratingstatus;
        public virtual string Rating 
        {
            get 
            {
                if (ProbableClassification != null && SeverityClassification != null)
                {
                    if (SeverityClassification.Severity == "Minor")
                    {
                        ratingstatus = "Low";
                    }
                    if (ProbableClassification.Probability == "Not Likely" && SeverityClassification.Severity == "Medium")
                    {
                        ratingstatus = "Low";
                    }
                    if (ProbableClassification.Probability == "Likely" && SeverityClassification.Severity == "Medium")
                    {
                        ratingstatus = "Medium";
                    }
                    if (ProbableClassification.Probability == "Definitely" && SeverityClassification.Severity == "Medium")
                    {
                        ratingstatus = "Medium";
                    }
                    if (ProbableClassification.Probability == "Not Likely" && SeverityClassification.Severity == "Major")
                    {
                        ratingstatus = "Low";
                    }
                    if (ProbableClassification.Probability == "Likely" && SeverityClassification.Severity == "Major")
                    {
                        ratingstatus = "High";
                    }
                    if (ProbableClassification.Probability == "Definitely" && SeverityClassification.Severity == "Major")
                    {
                        ratingstatus = "Crtical";
                    }

                }
            return ratingstatus;
            }
            set
            {
                ratingstatus = value;
            }
        }

        [Display(Name = "Due Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public virtual DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Assigned To")]
        public int StakeholderID { get; set; }
        public virtual Stakeholder Stakeholder { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Customer")]
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }

        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public virtual DateTime DateSubmitted { get; set; }
        public Issue()
        {
            this.DateSubmitted = DateTime.Now;
        }




    }
}
```